# Vue.js/React project root files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Is there a way to put these configuration files inside a /config folder, for example? Even if only a few. Although I always see it that way, I think it gets too polluted.

[root-project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz30x.png)

Thanks!

Comment: No, because you'll have to deal with each of libs that use these files to use alternative locations, and some of them definitely won't support this.